# Some of the parameters used in my genisoimage command don’t produce a bootable ISO image

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to extract all the files from a (bootable) Debian ISO and then re-generate a bootable ISO image. Below you can see the commands that I've issued. For some unknown reason,the generated ISO image does not boot. Can someone help me to understand why ? thanks.

```
apt update && apt -y install xorriso genisoimage

wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-11.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso

xorriso -osirrox on -indev debian-11.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso -extract / isofiles/

genisoimage -r -J -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o debian-11-unattended.iso isofiles
```

as you can see I haven't done any modification to the files inside the ISO image,so the error should be most likely on the latest command.

According with this post :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572751/how-to-make-a-reproducible-iso-file-with-mkisofs-genisoimage

I have also tried with this command :

```
mkisofs -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -v -T -V 'd-live 11.5.0 xf amd64' "isofiles/" > file.iso
```

but also in this case the ISO produced is not bootable : https://ibb.co/GstvTvR

I've omitted the parameter "**-reproducible-date=20221009**" because it hasn't been accepted. The error produced is : **"genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'producible-date=20221009'** and the ISO produced is only 32k.

This is how is the internal structure of the debian ISO file produced by the command above :

```
# isoinfo -d -i debian-11-unattended.iso

CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: LINUX
Volume id: d-live 11.5.0 xf amd64
Volume set id: 
Publisher id: 
Data preparer id: 
Application id: GENISOIMAGE ISO 9660/HFS FILESYSTEM CREATOR (C) 1993 E.YOUNGDALE (C) 1997-2006 J.PEARSON/J.SCHILLING (C) 2006-2007 CDRKIT TEAM
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 224756
El Torito VD version 1 found, boot catalog is in sector 1020
Joliet with UCS level 3 found
Rock Ridge signatures version 1 found
Eltorito validation header:
    Hid 1
    Arch 0 (x86)
    ID ''
    Key 55 AA
    Eltorito defaultboot header:
        Bootid 88 (bootable)
        Boot media 0 (No Emulation Boot)
        Load segment 0
        Sys type 0
        Nsect 4
        Bootoff 3FD 1021
```

the problem is in the lack of EFI boot lures: EFI System Partition for USB stick,EFI El Torito boot image for CD-ROM.

The solution is :

```
orig_iso=debian-live-11.5.0-amd64-xfce.iso
new_files=debian-live-11.5.0-amd64-xfce
new_iso=debian-live-11.5.0-amd64-mod-xfce.iso
mbr_template=isohdpfx.bin

# Extract MBR template file to disk
dd if="$orig_iso" bs=1 count=432 of="$mbr_template"

xorriso -as mkisofs \
   -r -J --joliet-long \
   -V 'd-live 11.5.0 xf amd64' \
   -o "$new_iso" \
   -isohybrid-mbr "$mbr_template" \
   -partition_offset 16 \
   -c isolinux/boot.cat \
   -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
   -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
   -eltorito-alt-boot \
   -e boot/grub/efi.img \
   -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus \
   "$new_files"
```

Comment: The ISO that you download is not bootable. You put it on a device that has been configured as bootable. That for example is what the Rufus program does, it makes the USB capable of booting.

Comment: the netinst image that I've downloaded is bootable : https://ibb.co/JmwdwWP. I didn't change anything of this image. I've downloaded and used as is.

Comment: That may be but are you not pulling the files from it?

Comment: what it means ?

Comment: can you give a look at this full log ? https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XyJKSf2mK8/

Comment: the problem was in the lack of EFI boot lures: EFI System Partition for USB stick,
EFI El Torito boot image for CD-ROM.